# SSIS Task to insert or update a row

Tags: sql-server, ssis, foreach-loop-container

Which kind of SSIS task should I use when I got some rows from a data source, then insert new row in destination or update the row in destination in case it exists.

I was thinking to use a SQL task for getting rows in a result set then use a for loop container. But I don't know how to continue further on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Lookup task](http://sqlhint.com/sqlserver/ssis/upsert-merge-with-integration-services):

- on match you execute an UPDATE statement via **OLE DB command**
- on error you add row in destination via **OLE DB destination task**

Answer (score 3):

The sequence for insert/update (without delete!) is very easy:
load your source (oleDB most likely) and your destination as wel as a source (again, most likely oleDB)

Merge Join on dest. table key

Conditional Split, on 1 side the rows from the source that exist (i.e. found a match in the join) on the other side the rest.

existing rows go to OLE DB command with an update query

new rows go to ole DB destination (or equivalent for your dest)

For a more complex method that includes delete see [this awesome blog](http://www.rad.pasfu.com/index.php?/archives/150-Insert,-Update,-and-Delete-Destination-table-with-SSIS.html)